# Recurring payments using Stripe and Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm still pretty new to Django and am trying to set up recurring payments via Stripe. I'm using Django 2.0 and have successfully set up a single charge test case. However, I'm unfamiliar with how to create recurring payments, and require it for the project I'm working on.

For the single payment, I have the following:

**Views**

```
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

def checkout(request):
    """Stripe check out"""

    new_tier = models.PaymentTier(
        level = "Tier 3",
        year = 2018
    )

    if request.method == "POST":
        token = request.POST.get("stripeToken")
    try:
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount = 2000,
            currency = "usd",
            source = token,
            description = "Tier 3 subscription for Elite Fitness"
        )

        new_tier.charge_id = charge.id

    except stripe.error.CardError as ce:
        return False, ce

    else:
        new_tier.save()
        return redirect("thank_you_page")



def payment_form(request):
    """Render stripe payment form template"""

    context = {"stripe_key": settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}
    return render(request, "stripe-template.html", context)




def thank_you_page(request):
    """Successful payment processed"""

    return render(request,'thank_you_page.html')
```

**stripe-template.html**

```
<form action="checkout/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key={{stripe_key}} # Make sure to wrap the variable name with double {}
        data-amount="2000"
        data-name="company name here"
        data-description="Elite Fitness Subscription"
        data-image="picture.png"
        data-currency="usd">
    </script>
</form>
```

I've had a difficult time finding anything online which covers recurring payments specifically. If anybody knows how to set them up (even through `dj-stripe` or `pinax`) any help will be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at the [Billing Quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart)-documentation.  It outlines step by step how to setup a subscription (or recurring payment).  The gist of it is, you first [create a product](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_product), then [create a plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan) with that product, [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) for whom you want to bill repeatedly, then [attach that plan as a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) to the customer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [create a plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_plan), you specify the recurring payment price and duration and then enroll your stripe customer on the plan [using subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_subscription).

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020 it's actually recommended to use `PaymentIntents` for this. Stripe has [an excellent guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price) for how to do this in their docs now that walks through the whole flow and covers things like 3D-secure as well.

For a longer treatment on the topic specific to Django, see this article: [How to Create a Subscription SaaS Application with Django and Stripe](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/django-stripe-integrate/)

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 I would suggest using the latest [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) and [Stripe Checkout session API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create). In your view you can create a new checkout session, and redirect straight to it (no JS required). Something roughly like this:

```py
def checkout(request):
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        success_url=redirect_url + "?stripe=success",
        cancel_url=redirect_url + "?stripe=cancel",
        mode="subscription",
        # `client_reference_id` will come back in the webhook,
        # making it easier to look up the associated object
        client_reference_id=obj.uuid,
        payment_method_types=["card"],
        line_items=[
            {
                "price": subscription_price_id,
                "quantity": 1,
            }
        ],
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(session.url, status=303)
```

Depending on your app, you'll probably also want to use the [Customer Portal sessions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal) (like Checkout sessions, but let's existing customers upgrade/cancel/etc.) and a webhook endpoint (if you need to do something when subscriptions are created or cancelled). A little bit longer writeup about that in [Django Forge docs](https://www.djangoforge.dev/docs/stripe/) and the [Stripe billing quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart) is also a good link still (updated to use these APIs, just not specific to Django).